# How to subtract every nth column in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have an arbitrary n*m matrix called data and I would like to take differences of the matrix using gradually bigger steps.

The first case would have a first column equal to `data(:,2)-data(:,1)`, the next column would be `data(:,3)-data(:,2)` and so on. This can be done with the following function.

```
data = diff(data,1,2)
```

Similarly I would also like to take differences based of every second column, so that the first entry would be `data(:,3)-data(:,1)` and the next `data(:,5)-data(:,3)` and so on.

This can't be done with diff, but is there any other function or method that can do it without resorting to looping?

I need to do the same thing for every n value up to 50.

Comment: And what happens to the even number columns? Do they stay or get removed in the output? What would be the size of the output w.r.t. `n` and `m`? If even num cols don't stay, then just remove them with `data(:,[2:2:end]=[]` and then use your `diff`.

Comment: Overall they will still be used whenever n (the step size is even) but I suppose I could do this as a work around. Would prolly still leave me looping though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `column indexing` to select the "right" columns and then use your favourite `diff`  -

```
A = randi(9,4,9) %// Input array
stepsize = 2; %// Edit this for a different stepsize
out = diff(A(:,1:stepsize:end),1,2)
```

Output -

```
A =
     8     9     9     8     3     2     6     8     7
     2     5     5     7     5     3     9     6     3
     2     7     7     2     4     1     2     4     1
     6     2     1     5     4     9     9     3     7
out =
     1    -6     3     1
     3     0     4    -6
     5    -3    -2    -1
    -5     3     5    -2
```

Comment: Why not just `diff(A(:,1:stepsize:end),1,2)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo That was embarrassing! Missed on that! :) Thanks!!

Comment: Not really. That's almost the same as you wrote in your comment :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Just curious, what made you delete your solution?

Comment: I deleted it because it answered a different question. I thought the OP didn't want to skip columns of the original matrix; that he just wanted to compute the n-th order difference. Besides, now that I think about it, the n-th order difference can be computed with `diff`; no need or `conv2`

Comment: For future reference, perhaps you should delete "logical" from your answer, now that you don't use logical indexing

Comment: @LuisMendo Good call on that! Edited.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a simple wrapper function for the purpose.

```
function [ out ] = diffhigh( matrix, offset )
    matrix_1 = matrix(:,(offset+1):size(matrix,1));
    matrix_2 = matrix(:, 1:(size(matrix,1)-offset));
    out = matrix_1 - matrix_2;
end


>> a

a =

    3     5     1     2     4
    1     2     3     4     5
    1     4     5     3     2
    1     2     4     3     5
    2     1     5     3     4


>> diffhigh(a, 2)

ans =

    -2    -3     3
     2     2     2
     4    -1    -3
     3     1     1
     3     2    -1

>> diffhigh(a, 3)

ans =

    -1    -1
     3     3
     2    -2
     2     3
     1     3
```